# How to disable JIT-Compiler (Just In Time Compiler) in Firefox?

Tags: firefox

Is it possible to disable JIT-Compiler in Firefox? I see some related config options:

```
javascript.options.baselinejit
javascript.options.wasm_baselinejit
javascript.options.wasm_optimizingjit 
javascript.options.ion
```

Is this enough to disable JIt or is there another way to do it?

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34315960/is-there-a-way-to-turn-off-jit-compiler-and-is-there-a-performance-impact-by-doi ?

Comment: And what’s your actual goal? Disabling the Javascript JIT compiler will have a great impact on Javascript performance.

Comment: My goal is to harden my browser by removing JIT-compiler and a lot of security related bugs with it.

Answer (score 2):

According to an article by German IT News outlet Heise you should set the following options to false:

- javascript.options.baselinejit
- javascript.options.ion
- javascript.options.wasm
- javascript.options.asmjs

Source: https://www.heise.de/news/Sicherer-oder-schneller-Microsoft-testet-Super-Duper-Secure-Mode-im-Browser-6162990.html

Heise references an article by Microsoft which concludes that the performance hit of disabling the JIT compiler in Microsoft Edge is not that big of an issue: https://microsoftedge.github.io/edgevr/posts/Super-Duper-Secure-Mode/